NOT PLUGIN FOUND FOR PREFIX http in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugin, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repo
I am running the command :
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=project-key -Dsonar.projectName=project-name -Dsonar.host.url=http://my.sonarurl.com/ -Dsonar.login=mytoken

in my environment I have:
Java 11
Apache Maven 3.9.6

and I am getting the following error:
ERROR : NOT PLUGIN FOUND FOR PREFIX http in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugin, org.codehaus.mojo] available in the repositories. 

I tried changing the version of sonar scanner
"mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar"

but I get the same error.

installed Java 22 and updated locally
set JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=“/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-22.jdk/Contents/Home”
java -version

